# What was the worst result for a president's trophy winner in the playoffs?

Tags: ice-hockey, nhl, postseason, stanley-cup

The Columbus Blue Jackets defeated the Tampa Bay Lightning in a [sweep](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/2019-columbus-blue-jackets-vs-tampa-bay-lightning-eastern-first-round.html) in the 1st round of the 2018-2019 NHL playoffs. Outside of this occurrence, what was the worst result for a President's Trophy winner in the playoffs?

There must have been some that got outed in the first round, but if so, what was the game score? 4-3? 4-1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There have been eight NHL teams thus far to win the [President's Trophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidents%27_Trophy) but be eliminated in the first round of the Stanley Cup Playoffs.

The worst Stanley Cup finish by a President's Trophy winner was in 2018-19 by the **[Tampa Bay Lightning](https://www.hockey-reference.com/teams/TBL/2019.html)**, who were eliminated in the first round by the Columbus Blue Jackets, in a 4-0 series.

Other President's Trophy winners eliminated in the first round are

- **[1991 Chicago Blackhawks](https://www.hockey-reference.com/teams/CHI/1991.html)** by Minnesota North Stars in a 4-2 series.
- **[2000 St Louis Blues](https://www.hockey-reference.com/teams/STL/2000.html)** by San Jose Sharks in a 4-3 series.
- **[2006 Detroit Red Wings](https://www.hockey-reference.com/teams/DET/2006.html)** by Edmonton Oilers in a 4-2 series.
- **[2009 San Jose Sharks](https://www.hockey-reference.com/teams/SJS/2009.html)** by Anaheim Ducks in a 4-2 series.
- **[2010 Washington Capitals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/teams/WSH/2010.html)** by Montreal Canadiens in a 4-3 series.
- **[2012 Vancouver Canucks](https://www.hockey-reference.com/teams/VAN/2012.html)** by Los Angeles Kings in a 4-1 series.
- **[2023 Boston Bruins](https://www.hockey-reference.com/teams/BOS/)** by Florida Panthers in a 4-3 series.

Answer (score -4):

As of the 2023 playoffs, The 2022-23 Boston Bruins now holds the worst result as a presidents trophy winner. Had a record breaking regular season only for them to lose in the first round to the Florida Panthers in 7 game. The Bruins blew a 3-1 series lead

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE. Please add a source to your answer

Comment: 1st round  0-4 has already been given by an existing answer, how does 1st round 3-4 form a worse playoff record?